# Search on array of strings column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, where-clause

I have a column name "multiselect_value" in which i am storing data as array of strings. Here is a sample

```
multiselect_value
["Books","Hockey","Movies"]
["Cricket","Books","Movies"]
```

Now i have a input value like ["Hockey","Books"] and i want to get those records in which this value exist in "multiselect_value" column

Here is what i have tried

```
SELECT user_id,multiselect_value 
FROM user_custom_field_data 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET("Books",multiselect_value) > 0;
```

Comment: It looks like `FIND_IN_SET()` expects the set to be in the form `Books,Hockey,Movies`, but your set is in the form `["Books","Hockey","Movies"]`. You'll probably have to use an expression to remove the leading and trailing brackets, and all the quotes, before you can use that column with `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, not as a table-type data view, or at least specify the column datatype. And specify precise MySQL version too.

Comment: *i have a input value like ["Hockey","Books"] and i want to get those records in which this value exist in "multiselect_value" column* Any one of or strictly both?

Comment: Any one of or strictly both?   i have both cases